# Using IF with curly brackets within IF without

Tags: php, if-statement

I have some code where i'm trying to use the different ifs within each other, but i ran into a problem.. I've made this testcode that will show the issue:

```
<?php
$test = 'lol';
if ($test == 'wat') :
    if (!empty($_GET['wat'])) {
        echo 'well';
    }
elseif ($test == 'lol') :
    echo 'loool';
endif;
die();
?>
```

This will return this error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /var/www/domain.com/public_html/test.php on line 7**

But that's only after i'm adding the **if (!empty($_GET['wat'])) { }**

The question is, am i doing something wrong, or isn't it possible to use a if with curly brackets within one without ?

Comment: It looks as though you are trying to use [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Which are very useful when using PHP as a 'templating language'. Alas, according to the manual:  _Note: Mixing syntaxes in the same control block is not supported._ If you change the inner 'if' to use the ':' syntax then it works as expected.

Comment: Just do it the right way. Its bad code, and a bad idea. Put the brackets in to make it clear and obvious what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish using basic `if` syntax in an alternative `if` syntax statement, but you probably should avoid it. It's a bit wonky, but the following syntax works fine:

```
$condition = "test";
$other = null;
if ($condition == "test") :
    if (isset($other))
        echo "Set";
    else
        echo "Not Set";
elseif ($condition == "something") :
    echo "Huh";
endif;
```

The above would echo "Not Set" as `$condition == "test"` is true, and `$other` isn't set.

I think what your example is missing is the closing `else` statement on your basic syntax if statement (which I know isn't needed, but seems to cause issues in this case). Modifying your code to:

```
$test = "lol";
if ($test == "wat") :
    if (!empty($_GET["wat"]))
        echo "well";
    else
        echo "Nothing";
elseif ($test == "lol") :
    echo "loool";
endif;
```

Causes it to compile and run just fine. It's weird, but it seems to work.

Hope that provides some insight!

**Edit**

For multiple lines, just add brackets to the inside `if` statement:

```
$test = "lol";
if ($test == "wat") :
  if (!empty($_GET["wat"])){
    echo "well";
    // Do something else
  } else {
    echo "Nothing";
    // More Stuff
  }
elseif ($test == "lol") :
  echo "loool";
endif;
```

Comment: Have an idea how i would do if have multiple lines ? ^^

Comment: See my edit, shows how to handle multiple lines on the inside `if` statement (just add brackets).

Comment: No problem! As others have said, it's probably best to stick with one or the other, but it's still good to know how they both work, so this was an interesting example. Cheers!